# ssh -> authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

***sudo cat idenityfile.rsa > authorized_keys***
-bash: authorized_keys: Permission denied

if I su - to the user then I can do this but why can I not do this with sudo from my user?

Comment: Dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/213347/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `>` redirection does not work like this with sudo.

You can use these alternative:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat idenityfile.rsa > authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the redirect isn't "sudo"ed  Try something like this instead:

sudo bash -c “cat idenityfile.rsa > authorized_keys”