# `sudo echo "bla" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, sudo

Disclaimer: I'm pretty novice at sysadmin stuff.

I'm trying to set up port forwarding in an AWS EC2 instance, this has to be done in the command-line because I don't want to go in and edit anything, it has to be automatic (it's part of a build process).

```
sudo echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

> Permission denied

The weird thing is I've been (successfully) using `sudo` for pretty much every command that required `su` privileges. If I do `sudo su` before the command (trying it out by hand in an `ssh` session), then it works.

Reasons behind this? Possible solutions that don't involve `sudo su` or manual edits?

Comment: Same problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr -- Also, if you want to be really risky: `sudo -i`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't use `sudo` to affect output redirection; `>` and `>>` (and, for completeness, `<`) are effected with the privilege of the calling user, because redirection is done by the calling shell, not the called subprocess.

Either do

```
cp /etc/sysctl.conf /tmp/
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /tmp/sysctl.conf
sudo cp /tmp/sysctl.conf /etc/
```

or

```
sudo /bin/su -c "echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
```

Answer (score 22):

You might find it simpler to use this command:

```
echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 14):

`sudo` runs only your command, not the redirect, as root.  You'll need to wrap it all in a command where the whole thing runs as root:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
```

Answer (score 4):

The command `sudo echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` is interpreted as that **you** (nonroot) write the result of `sudo echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1"` into /etc/sysctl.conf.

Run

```
sudo -s 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
```

or

```
sudo su -c 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'
```

to run `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` as root.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo sed -i "$ a <text>" <file>
```

- `-i`  : edit file in place.
- `$ a`: append text to the last line

Using `sed` command avoids you the hassle of redirections and pipelines.

In your case: `sudo sed -i "$ a net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" /etc/sysctl.conf`