# Self-signed TLS1.2 certificate handshake failure

Tags: debian, ssl, openssl, tls

I have been trying to set up a self-signed SSL cert on my Debian install as per this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ecc-certificate-on-nginx-for-debian-8 but I am getting the following error when connecting:

```
openssl s_client -connect vpsipaddr:443 -state -debug
    CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x7d3380 [0x7d3f10] (289 bytes => 289 (0x121))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 1c 01 00 01-18 03 03 62 c4 ec 46 0b   ...........b..F.
0010 - 47 d3 35 9a f1 b4 54 11-fe 85 66 b8 e7 70 a2 e6   G.5...T...f..p..
0020 - 1e 4c 57 11 75 81 86 be-53 d6 0e 00 00 82 c0 30   .LW.u...S......0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
0050 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0060 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0070 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a-00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0080 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
0090 - 00 96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07-c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04   ...A............
00a0 - c0 12 c0 08 00 16 00 13-c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 ff   ................
00b0 - 01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04-03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34   ...m...........4
00c0 - 00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19-00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09   .2..............
00d0 - 00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08-00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15   ................
00e0 - 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13-00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f   ................
00f0 - 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00-00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01   .....#..... ....
0100 - 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02-05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03   ................
0110 - 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01-02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01   ................
0120 - 01                                                .
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0x7d3380 [0x7d9470] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
139916497704592:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1473161145
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere else, not quite sure how to debug the error though I've tried. Thank you!

Comment: Does `openssl x509 -noout -text < /path/to/your/cert.pem` print what you expect? Does a configuration test on nginx report everything is fine?

Comment: I'm trying to run the command with sudo but I get
-bash: /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.pem: Permission denied

Comment: Update: I don't know if your command was wrong or not, but when running openssl x509 -noout -text -in /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.pem with sudo I get the proper response.

Comment: That's an unrelated issue; `sudo`doesn't work with shell IO redirection, see eg [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/540492/55514) for more details on that.

Answer (score 4):

```
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0x7d3380 [0x7d9470] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
139916497704592:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

The server is closing the connection directly after receiving the ClientHello. There are various possibilities why this happens:

- Server expects SNI extension. Try to use the `-servername hostname` option with the configured hostname (not IP address) to see if this helps to get a connection.
- Bad configuration of the server, like wrong certificate setup or even no SSL at all on port 443. Check the error_log and access_log of the server for more information. Other kinds of bad setups might be the choice of Ciphers or Protocols but usually one gets a different error back then.