# How to secure Monit web interface with SSL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, openssl

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server and I installed Monit.

I want to secure the web interface. I followed the following instructions :

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/monit

```
$ cd /var/certs
$ sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -config ./monit.cnf -out /var/certs/monit.pem -keyout /var/certs/monit.pem
$ sudo openssl gendh 512 >> /var/certs/monit.pem
$ sudo openssl x509 -subject -dates -fingerprint -noout -in /var/certs/monit.pem
$ sudo chmod 700 /var/certs/monit.pem
```

**1)** When I run the following command I got an error. Yet I do it with "sudo". Why is it not working ?

```
ubuntu@myserver /var/certs $ sudo openssl gendh 512 >> /var/certs/monit.pem
-bash: /var/certs/monit.pem: Permission denied
```

**2)** It says in the address bar "not secure", yet I am using HTTPS. Is this normal ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmJEI.png)

I would also like to know what these 2 command lines are for :

```
$ sudo openssl gendh 512 >> /var/certs/monit.pem
$ sudo openssl x509 -subject -dates -fingerprint -noout -in /var/certs/monit.pem
```

Comment: `It says in the address bar "not secure", yet I am using HTTPS. Is this normal ?` Yes it is normal. What is not normal is using an IP address for an HTTPS connection.

Comment: @GregAskew It's not my site, it's Monit a monitoring service. I followed the documentation and the service at its own port

Answer (score 0):

Using redirection when running a `sudo` command doesn't do what you expect, you have to change it to something like:

```
sudo bash -c "openssl gendh 512 >> /var/certs/monit.pem"
```

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/540492/sudo-echo-bla-etc-sysctl-conf-permission-denied) for more information.

Comment: Invalid command 'gendh'; type "help" for a list.

Comment: Thank you, I tested and it does not work

Comment: @mathieu, I simply copied the command you said you entered in your question