# Permission denied after chattr use

Tags: linux, chattr

tried chattr on a file but can't revert it's effect.

currently it looks like

```
lsattr /path/myfile
--------------e----- /path/myfile
ls -la /path/myfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul  5 11:12 /pat/myfile
```

still

```
sudo echo "text" > /path/myfile
-bash: /path/myfile: Permission denied
```

Is there any solution so that I can write with sudo or revert the chattr settings ?

Comment: Do these answer your question? https://serverfault.com/questions/540492/sudo-echo-bla-etc-sysctl-conf-permission-denied https://serverfault.com/questions/1000184/why-can-i-update-a-file-owned-by-root-using-sudo-vi-but-not-append-a-line-to-it/1000186#1000186

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt thanks for that. It explains the background. Not sure if I ever enncountered that before.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt thanks you already clarified with the first reply. I was able to solve the issue